# Cucumber scenario fails

Tags: cucumber

I have this lines in my scenario and the second fails:

```
Then I should see "blogger_1"
And I should not see "blogger_2"

And I should not see "blogger_2"                                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:147
  expected #has_no_content?("blogger_2") to return true, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:149:in `/^(?:|I )should not see "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/merge_articles.feature:46:in `And I should not see "blogger_2"'
```

There is a saved page from cpybara:

http://ge.tt/3VNhKDS/v/0

Comment: can you show us the scenario and give us some more context?

Comment: and I can't immediately open that russian download link - why don't you put it in dropbox or something?

Comment: what's the error message when it fails?  stack trace?

Comment: 1. there is nothing to see
2. I don't have Dropbox app or whatever it needs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have blogger_2 appearing in the html option, so you need a more sophisticated definition to check for the text in the correct place, e.g. https://makandracards.com/makandra/5793-test-whether-a-form-field-exists-with-cucumber-and-capybara

Comment: ah, and this is even more relevant, shows you how to examine the select options: https://makandracards.com/makandra/996-test-that-a-select-field-contains-an-option-with-cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I've made this step definition to check that word not in table cell

```
Then /^(?:|I )should not see "([^"]*)" in table$/ do |text|
  regexp = Regexp.new('<td>'+text+'</td>')
  assert page.body =~ regexp ? false : true
end
```